# Calculate Intra class coefficient for all combination of column in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, coefficients

I would like a little help/sample example as to how to calculate ICC for a combination of variable in R.

For ex Below is sample dataset:- [image: Sample dataset]

Now I want to do exhaustive search for all 2 gene combinations (Columns are gene names) and respective ICC, then for 3 gene combination, then for four. Post that I want to list the combination sorted wrt ICC values

The output would look something like this

[image: Output]

I have tried to do the same using below code, but I am struggling to work this exhaustive search & combination thing

```
mat1 <- as.matrix(lmm_1[,1:10])
icc(mat1, model = c("t"),r0 = 0,conf.level = 0.95)
icc(lmer( YWHAZ~ ., data = mat1))
```

My dataframe structure lmm_1 is as below, Please help on this

```
structure(list(`HKG1 (18S)` = c(140922.090379318, 114050.66128233, 
231970.660810084), `HKG2 (GAPDH)` = c(5821646.94272285, 4054004.07527754, 
8279934.32892469), `HKG3 (ACTB)` = c(513559.47728841, 682673.286801917, 
890579.00053991), `HKG4 (HMBS)` = c(963904.825829829, 1298738.62059259, 
2091567.68645239), `HKG5 (HPRT)` = c(5508533.08283376, 5516876.07150713, 
10236502.8076606), `HKG6 (SDHA)` = c(115259.913117015, 127680.131645604, 
260533.935040935), `HKG7 (PABPN1)` = c(1483557.685172, 1212117.22511327, 
1823406.16115662), `HKG8 (TBP)` = c(1835256.87785655, 1633084.68373014, 
2478000.07992693), `HKG9 (YWHAG` = c(5892446.87038693, 6039118.46057885, 
11746762.2003624), `HKG10 (YWHAZ )` = c(250987.289730308, 250536.411475335, 
814508.745534441), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), ID = c(1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Team, Please help!

Comment: Anyone, do tell me in case I am asking it in wrong way

Comment: Please assist me team, struggling to get answers anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick code example that might help (the second example). https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/intraclass-correlation-coefficients-example/